# Make every day a yoga day Vs Make every day yoga day

Tags: grammar

I see both versions on the internet.

1. Make every day a yoga day.
2. Make every day yoga day.

What is the difference?

Comment: There is no significant difference. The second one  is imagining that there is a special day for doing yoga (like Remembrance Day for remembering the war dead, International Women's Day etc.).

Comment: Omitting "a" makes it sound more definite and forceful. But a Google search will show examples of "Make every day" with and without "a", e.g. both "Make every day an Employee Appreciation Day" and "Make every day Employee Appreciation Day" (which is apparently an annual event some people celebrate). This seems a matter of opinion.

Comment: Capitalization would help: Make every day Yoga Day.

Answer (score 1):

The first phrase, ***a** yoga day*, is the more typical form - not to say that it's necessarily more commonly spoken, but it *describes* something more typical.

Compare: *today is a workday*

A work day is a day on which you work.  There are many such days, and any one of them is not that special - it's just a(nother) workday.

And then compare: *today is Graduation Day*

Graduation Day (not **a** graduation day) is the day when you, or someone you care about graduates from school.  It's a big event, and it's rare, so it gets what's essentially a proper name, like a holiday.

Thus, *a yoga day* would be any of the days on which you do yoga; by using the phrase, you imply that these days are pretty typical.  Whereas *yoga day* (or *Yoga Day*) is a more special, and probably rarer event.  I might expect to see the phrases used like this:

*Today is a yoga day, so I'll be home a little late tonight*

*Today is Yoga Day; I've packed my special outfit, I cleaned my yoga mat, and I'm trying to stay off of the internet so that I'll be focused and really present.*

Of your examples, there's nothing very unusual about "make every day a yoga day" - it simply means, do yoga every day, or make yoga part of your daily routine.

"Make every day yoga day" is potentially a more interesting, though it would depend on context.  I'd assume, if I read this in an advertisement, that it just meant the same thing - do yoga every day - with a subtext that we're probably not supposed to think about: transform what had been a special occasion (Yoga Day) into an everyday routine.

But there is another way to read the sentence: treat every day like you treat the special occasion of Yoga Day - be very mindful and disciplined and seek enlightenment every day, not just occasionally.  This would be similar to the cliché live every day like it's your last.  There's a certain kind of self-help guru who, if I heard them say "make every day yoga day", I'd interpret this way.

Comment: This explanation is generally good, but I'd like to highlight a usage pattern. When discussing exercise, it is very common to use simply '_____ day' to describe the day (usually the day of the week, but sometimes a longer workout cycle) to describe the day on which you work out ______ (a body part/muscle group) or a day in which you work out by doing _____ (an activity): 'leg day,' 'cardio day,' 'basketball day,' 'yoga day,' etc.

Comment: Yes, the adjective in front of *day* can be used to refer to a day set aside for the activity mentioned.   *Wednesday is laundry day. Thursday is date night.*